# Getting HDR colors before tonemapping is applied in SCNTechnique shader

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I am writing a custom shader to postprocess the rendering of SceneKit using SCNTechnique.

I have a pass with inputs set to COLOR, which provides me the result of the SceneKit render. Unfortunately, COLOR provides me SDR colors with SceneKit's tonemapping already applied. I have set `wantsHDR` to true on my camera.

Is there any way to get the pre-processed HDR colors so I can write a shader that processes those instead?